# MongoDB индексы для sort

Tags: запрос, mongodb, индексы

В MongoDB производится `find()` по двум полям, ещё одно поле используется для сортировки. Пример кода:

```
$limit = 10;
$skip = ( $page - 1 ) * $limit;

$query = [
    'conditions'    => [ 'channel_id' => $channel_id, 'author' => $author_id ],
    'sort'          => [ 'created_at' => -1 ],
    'skip' => $skip,
    'limit' => $limit
];

$publications = Pull::find( $query );
```

Для полей, по которым происходит выбор, я сделал так (в консоли MongoDB):

```
createIndex( { 'channel_id' : 1, 'author_id' : 1 } )
```

А вот с полем `created_at`, по которому происходит сортировка, как быть? создавать ему индекс отдельно, или пихнуть тоже в составной индекс? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порядок полей должен быть:

1. Сначала поля которые отбираются по точным значениям.
2. Далее поля по которым будет идти сортировка.
3. И в конце поля для диапазонного фильтра.

В конец составного индекса.
Тут рассмотрен вопрос более подробно https://habrahabr.ru/post/147053/

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ. Материал из ссылки должно также присутствовавть в теле ответа.